# Excel – Multiple Columns, Different Combinations

Tags: excel

I have 4 columns with 4 different parameters, if that's the right word. Each parameter has about 3-5 variables. What I want to do is I want to create ALL possible combinations of the 4 different parameters while maintaining the different columns. So let's say I have the following as an example:

```
**Column A | Column B | Column C**

Chicago  | Football | Red 

New York | Soccer   | White

Seattle  | Hockey   | Blue
```

What I want is to have, all the combinations I could get out of those columns, which I can illustrate as:

```
**Column A | Column B | Column C**

New York | Football | Blue 

New York | Football | Red

New York | Football | White

New York | Soccer   | Blue 

New York | Soccer   | Red

New York | Soccer   | White

New York | Hockey   | Blue 

New York | Hockey   | Red

New York | Hockey   | White

Chicago  | Football | Blue 

Chicago  | Football | Red

Chicago  | Football | White...
```

and so on.

Comment: You have multiple answers to do what you are asking.  Some feedback on the methods would be great.  What worked, what didn't.  If one worked for you then mark it as correct.  Click on the green check mark by the answer that worked for you.  It is something only you can do.  It will close out the question as answered and reward the party that was best able to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Edit with Office 365 we can use:

```
=LET(
    rng,A1:C3,
    rw,ROWS(rng),
    clm,COLUMNS(rng),
    SORT(MAKEARRAY(rw^clm,clm,LAMBDA(a,b,INDEX(rng,INT(MOD(a,rw^b)/(rw^b/rw))+1,b))),SEQUENCE(,clm)))
```

Original vba answer.

This will give you every combination possible:

```
Function fifth(arr() As Variant) As Variant()

Dim temp() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim t As Long

ReDim temp(1 To (UBound(arr, 1)) ^ (UBound(arr, 2)), LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)) As Variant
For i = 1 To (UBound(arr, 1) ^ UBound(arr, 2))
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        t = Int((i Mod ((UBound(arr)) ^ j)) / (((UBound(arr)) ^ j) / (UBound(arr))))
        temp(i, j) = arr(t + 1, j)
    Next j
Next i

fifth = temp

End Function
```

You would call thus:

```
Sub ArrCombine()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arr1() As Variant
Dim rsltarr() As Variant

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet

arr1 = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Value

rsltarr = fifth(arr1)

ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).Resize(UBound(rsltarr, 1) - 1, UBound(rsltarr, 2)).Value = rsltarr

End Sub
```

It will output on the active sheet, this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

This will use any size range.  The only restriction is that `#ofRows ^ #ofColumns` is not greater than the number of rows available on the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I made a terrible mistake. Didn't check out my whole excel. You need to apply 4 formulas.

Copy in D1:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($D$1)+1<=COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)*COUNTA(C:C),INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-ROW($D$1))/(COUNTA(B:B)*COUNTA(C:C))+1)),"")
```

Copy in E1:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($E$1)+1<=COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)*COUNTA(C:C),INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-ROW($E$1),COUNTA(B:B))+1),"")
```

Copy in F1:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($F$1)+1<=COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)*COUNTA(C:C),INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),COUNTA(B:B))+1),"")
```

Finally copy in G1:

```
=+D1&" "&E1&" "&F1
```

What is does is counts the cells of each column, and if there is not enough for each combination (leng(A)*leng(B)*leng(C)), it adds one more element.

[image]

Comment: Due to the complexity of this formula, the value of the answer would be greaty increased if you were to walk through the steps of what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

To do it by formula I suggest something like that:

In Row 1 we use helper-cells for now (to speed it up for longer lists)

In Columns A to D i have some variables (3 to 5) and for my list i use columns F to I. F1 simply has `=COUNTA(A:A)` (copied till I1 -> `=COUNTA(D:D)`)

```
F2: =INDEX(A:A,MOD(INT((ROW()-2)/PRODUCT(G$1:$I$1)),F$1)+1)
```

Can be autofilled to H2

```
G2: =INDEX(B:B,MOD(INT((ROW()-2)/PRODUCT(H$1:$I$1)),G$1)+1)
H2: =INDEX(C:C,MOD(INT((ROW()-2)/PRODUCT(I$1:$I$1)),H$1)+1)
```

I2 get a slight different formula:

```
I2: =INDEX(D:D,MOD(ROW()-2,$I$1)+1)
```

now select F2 to I2 and auto-fill down till column F shows the first value again... or do a `=PRODUCT(F1:H1)+1` -> this is your last row ;)

it can be simply enhanced because except for the right column, the formulas are auto-fill-able. simply insert a column before column A and F and type in A what you also need to be there. Column G can be auto-filled from column H. Don't forget to extend the list downwards as you need it. if you still have any questions, just ask.

[image]

Doing it via VBA is suggest something like that:

```
Sub test()
  Dim inputRng As Range
  Set inputRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:E") 'change this to fit your needs

  Dim inputVal() As Variant
  ReDim inputVal(1 To inputRng.Columns.Count)
  Dim holder() As Variant
  Dim i, j, k, xCol, xRow
  j = 1: k = 1

  'load in values
  For Each xCol In inputRng.Columns
    xRow = Cells(1, xCol.Column).End(xlDown).Row
    ReDim holder(0 To xRow)
    holder(0) = xRow
    j = j * xRow

    For i = 1 To xRow
      holder(i) = xCol.Cells(i).Value
    Next

    inputVal(k) = holder
    k = k + 1
  Next

  Dim outputVal() As Variant
  ReDim outputVal(1 To j, 1 To inputRng.Columns.Count)
  k = 1

  For i = UBound(outputVal, 2) To 1 Step -1
    For j = 0 To UBound(outputVal) - 1
      outputVal(j + 1, i) = inputVal(i)((Int(j / k) Mod inputVal(i)(0)) + 1)
    Next
    k = k * inputVal(i)(0)
  Next

  Dim outputRng As Range
  Set outputRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G1")  'set here the first cell to start output

  outputRng.Resize(UBound(outputVal), UBound(outputVal, 2)).Value = outputVal

End Sub
```

It is designed to work with different sizes for each spot and you only need to change 2 lines to perfectly fit your needs. :)

Warning: If one spot only has 1 item, it will fail! (Excel may not respond anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you know there is a maximum of 5 options in each of the 3 columns (the title of the question says 4, but the example shows 3). Then it is possible to recast this as a problem of counting from 0 to 124 (5^3-1) in base 5. Here's how.
In E1 place `=BASE(ROW()-1,5,3)` and drag that down through row 125, to do the counting, filling left to length 3 with leading 0s. Then pick apart the digits by filling in `=mid(E1,1,1), =mid(E1,2,1), and =mid(E1,3,1)` in columns F through H and dragging that all the way down.
Now choose the corresponding tuples by placing `=index(A$1:A$5,1+F1)` in column I, dragging right to columns J and K, and all the way down for all 3 columns.
This will contain some incomplete items if not everything has 5 options. To eliminate those, we blank them and sort them to the end as follows. In L1 place `=IF(COUNTA(I1:K1)=3, join(",",I1:K1),"")` and drag down through line 125.
In M1, we sort the empties to the end by `=sort(L1:L125,1,false)` (which also re-sorts the other items, but no matter, they are still all there). Finally, we unsplit the items again, by putting in N1 `=split(M1,",")` and dragging it down as far as there are non-empty 3-tuples. Columns N, O, and P will contain the desired output.
If one wishes to take down the scaffolding with which these were built, one may hide all the columns in which the work was done. Doubtless one could also compact the functions into something terser but more inscrutable.
This approach can be generalized to other bases if there are more (or fewer) options, and it presumably could also be made dynamic with things like replacing 5 with the MAX of the counts of each of the first 3 columns.