# Excel - How to Find All Possible Combinations For 4 Columns - (No VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple 4 column table below:

```
  Column A      Column B        Column C      Column D
  HEAD          BODY            PARAGRAPH     IMAGE
  Headline 1    Body Text 1     Paragraph 1   Image 1
  Headline 2    Body Text 2     Paragraph 2   Image 2
  Headline 3    Body Text 3     Paragraph 3   Image 3
```

What I want is to have, all the combinations I could get out of those columns, which I can illustrate as:

```
  Column F      Column G        Column H      Column I
  HEAD          BODY            PARAGRAPH     IMAGE
  Headline 1    Body Text 1     Paragraph 1   Image 1
  Headline 1    Body Text 1     Paragraph 1   Image 2
  Headline 1    Body Text 1     Paragraph 1   Image 3
  Headline 2    Body Text 2     Paragraph 2   Image 1
  Headline 2    Body Text 2     Paragraph 2   Image 2
  Headline 2    Body Text 2     Paragraph 2   Image 3
  Headline 3    Body Text 3     Paragraph 3   Image 1
  Headline 3    Body Text 3     Paragraph 3   Image 2
  Headline 3    Body Text 3     Paragraph 3   Image 3
  etc.
```

Basically I want the same answer as - [Excel – Multiple Columns, Different Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295430/excel-multiple-columns-different-combinations) but only for 4 columns and not 3 and no VBA please.

Comment: may we assume the same number of options in each column? Also your solutions have an image4 but problem does not?

Comment: Fixed the Image 4 i made an error by putting it there, I would like be able to change the number of options in each column

Comment: Oh. Because I had a solution for the same number of options in each column. In your example I was construing answers as a 4 digit base 3 number, then converting the ternary digits back to options). That works nicely if there are 3 (or n) of each. If not, I suppose I can add some ugliness to handle it, but I like it less. Do you want me to write what I have so far as an answer?

Comment: Yes! Please write what you have so far

Comment: Done. I'm editing to show what to do if not.

Comment: For now at least, here is a link to a Google sheet for it (though if I could really use Google sheets, I'd use UNIQUE rather than SORT). https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IxrkwlALO6MnyLA8Zs5LqUIMd-ePqZACNN92sDnuCnU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The solution by @Dirk Reichel in the place you cite is for 4 columns and has a no vba option. You may prefer it to mine. It is definitely inherently more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if we think about everything as a 4 digit number, where in the example given because there are 3 options in each column, we would want a base 3 number. I am writing it up for 3, but it should be clear how to extend it. A little below, I'll indicate how to handle different numbers of options in each column.
Suppose your data appears in A1:D4. I chose to leave column E blank so I could read things easily. F1 got the following formula:

```
=mid(base(row()-1,3,4),1,1)
```

which construes the row number - 1 (1-1=0, here) as a 4 digit base 3 number and takes the first digit.
G1 has the 2nd digit: `=mid(base(row()-1,3,4),2,1)`
H1 has `=mid(base(row()-1,3,4),3,1)`
and I1 has `=mid(base(row()-1,3,4),4,1)`

Then select F1:I1 and drag down through row 81 (which will have 2 2 2 2).
J1 gets `=index(A$2:A$4,1+F1)`, which gets dragged right through M1.
Then drag J1:M1 down through row 81, and you have all the ones you want.

[later you can hide columns that were work columns or build their formulas into more inscrutable ones.]

Now suppose you want to be able to handle the case where there are different numbers of options in each category. Let's assume n is the largest number of options. I'll illustrate for n=3, but again it should be generalizable.

Assuming the possibilities sit in columns J:M, In N1, I placed `=if(counta(J1:M1)=4,join(",",J1:M1),"")`, and dragged that all the way down to keep all the things that have one thing in each category present, but the phantom entries totally blank. In O1 I put `=sort(N1:N,1,false)` to send the blanks to the bottom, and then for the rows until the blanks, in P1 and dragged on down place `=split(O1,",")`.

There are some possible generalizations here where when I used numbers but you could use counts of entries in your columns, but I think this should get you pretty far. There is also a limitation in this approach that you cannot have more than 36 of any choice.