# MS365 Formula to Concatenate All Combinations of Values in One Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking to get all possible combinations of currencies from a list:

| Currency Code |
| --- |
| USD |
| JPY |
| BGN |
| CZK |
| DKK |
| GBP |
| HUF |
| PLN |
| RON |
| SEK |
| CHF |
| ISK |
| NOK |
| TRY |
| AUD |
| BRL |
| CAD |
| CNY |
| HKD |
| IDR |
| ILS |
| INR |
| KRW |
| MXN |
| MYR |
| NZD |
| PHP |
| SGD |
| THB |
| ZAR |
| EUR |

Looking to output USD-USD, USD-JPY, JPY-USD etc for all possible combinations.

Is there a way to have the output be a dynamic array using the MS365 formulas?

what ive tried:

```
=TOCOL(MyTable[@Currency]&TRANSPOSE(MyTable[@Currency]))
```

Comment: Duplicate the column. Then you can easily modify this answer of [@ScottCraner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295430/excel-multiple-columns-different-combinations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to combine the same currencies, as well as the following approach shown below doesn't require a <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> iteration.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, A2:A32,
     φ, TOROW(α),
     TOCOL(IFS(ISERR(FIND(φ,α)),α&"-"&φ),3))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
=TOCOL(MAP(TOCOL(A1:A31&"-"&TRANSPOSE(A1:A31)),LAMBDA(x,IF(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,"-"),,1)<>INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,"-"),,2),x,NA()))),3)
```

Result:

[image]

```
=TOCOL(A1:A31&"-"&TRANSPOSE(A1:A31))
```

Is used to get full list, rest of the formula is to exclude *USD-USD*, *JPY-JPY* and etc.